# Xcode built-in png compression effects

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit, compression, png

I have a question about png-8 vs png-24 usage vs Xcode's built in ["image compressor"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/1-Build_Setting_Reference/build_setting_ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003931-CH3-SW6).

Some images converted to png-8 are just fine saved like that, because difference between png-24 version can't be noticed easily. But some images have to be stored as png-24 so that quality remains at high level... Same image is about 3 times smaller when saved like png-8, so I guess there would be some benefits in memory consumption when using png-8 vs png-24. But what I am not sure is:

- Does iOS "likes" more png-24 ?
- Are there any problems with using png-8 instead of png-24 in iOS and what is a preferred choice ?
- What are benefits to optimize image in PS (or some program like TexturePacker) when COMPRESS_PNG_FILES in Xcode is set to YES because I suppose Xcode in some way overwrites our optimization done in PS?
- What actually Xcode does when optimizing images?

I know that just letting Xcode to do what it suppose to do is probably more than enough, especially for newer devices with enough memory and cpu power, but I am curios what's happening "under the hood" and is it wasting of time doing optimization in Photoshop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Does iOS "likes" more png-24?

iOS certainly likes its images to be close to its own hardware format (see below). However, it may not *presume* a certain format, or convert images at will. This would mean that the default postprocessing could convert images from palettized (8-bit) to true-color images, and that would be *destructive* if the application expects its images to contain a palette. There are many good & proper uses of palettized images.

> - Are there any problems with using png-8 instead of png-24 in iOS and what is a preferred choice?

Color depth - higher is better, for some kinds of images (but not all). Size - smaller is better (and for deciding when, you are on your own). Other than Sangony states, the PNG specification is generous enough to allow more than a single bit of alpha even in indexed mode. That is, the usual RGB palette may also be RGBA, including alpha. I am not aware of any "problems" with more common PNG formats, or even the uncommon ones.

> - What are benefits to optimize image in PS (or some program like TexturePacker) when COMPRESS_PNG_FILES in Xcode is set to YES because I suppose Xcode in some way overwrites our optimization done in PS?

Photoshop is not *extremely* good at optimizing PNGs, but then again it's certainly not one of the worst. `pngcrush` (the original) is written specifically to try and squeeze the very last byte out of a PNG -- but at its highest setting, it can really take a while to do so. I may have used Apple's modified `pngcrush` unknowingly, since it is "on" by default; I have not found such a huge delay when compiling code, so Apple's default may be not the highest *possible* setting. This suggests that manually running `pngcrush` could be worth the time, in which case you definitely do not want XCode to undo it.

> - What actually Xcode does when optimizing images?

The most visible 'optimizations' are: switching storage order from RGB to BGR and discarding the alpha channel by premultiplying it with the color channels. See also [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21008079/2564301).

The storage order thingy is, presumably, optimal for the default target devices (iPads, iPhones). Premultiplying alpha is a common method of optimizing, because then it takes less calculations to display the images in real time. (There are some disadvantages to it as well.)

Without any exact measurements, one can only speculate if these optimizations really matter on modern hardware. All internal conversions to 'display' format may very well be cached as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer...I will read it carefully once again to catch all the details.

Answer (score 2):

Xcode uses [PngCrush](http://pmt.sourceforge.net/pngcrush/) behind the scenes to optimize .png files. [Here](https://imageoptim.com/xcode.html) is also a good blog post that can answer your questions.

Comment: In those links I've found that using png-8 is certainly possible, but it's not recommended. Here is the link : http://bjango.com/articles/pngcompression/ But there is no explanation why is that? Do you have any idea, why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the available colors between PNG8 and PNG 24, the main difference is the the transparency aspect.

PNG8 alpha can sometimes be somewhat jagged in appearance whereas PNG24 is much smoother. If alpha is not a concern for you and the image looks good enough, then PNG8 is probably the way to go.

**PNG8 Alpha**
[image: PNG8]

**PNG24 Alpha**
[image: PNG24]

Comment: Yeap, I don't bother in this case with alpha. Just tried to save a background image as png-24 and png-8 and for this particular case, there was really no difference noticeable by closely looking at both. But there was noticeable difference in size, which is 800kb vs 300kb. So, I was curious what iOS/Spritekit likes better...